# Very slow MySQL query performance

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mysql-5.7

I've a query that takes about **18 seconds** to finish:

**THE QUERY:**

```
SELECT YEAR(c.date), MONTH(c.date), p.district_id, COUNT(p.owner_id)
FROM commission c
  INNER JOIN partner p ON c.customer_id = p.id
WHERE (c.date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31')
  AND (c.company_id = 90)
  AND (c.source = 'ACTUAL')
  AND (p.id IN (3062, 3063, 3064, 3065, 3066, 3067, 3068, 3069, 3070, 3071,
    3072, 3073, 3074, 3075, 3076, 3077, 3078, 3079, 3081, 3082, 3083, 3084,
    3085, 3086, 3087, 3088, 3089, 3090, 3091, 3092, 3093, 3094, 3095, 3096,
    3097, 3098, 3099, 3448, 3449, 3450, 3451, 3452, 3453, 3454, 3455, 3456,
    3457, 3458, 3459, 3460, 3461, 3471, 3490, 3491, 6307, 6368, 6421))
  GROUP BY YEAR(c.date), MONTH(c.date), p.district_id
```

The `commission` table has around **2,8 millions** of records, of which **860 000+** belong to the current year 2018. The `partner` table has at this moment 8600+ records.

**RESULT**

```
| `YEAR(c.date)` | `MONTH(c.date)` | district_id | `COUNT(c.id)` | 
|----------------|-----------------|-------------|---------------| 
| 2018           | 1               | 1           | 19154         | 
| 2018           | 1               | 5           | 9184          | 
| 2018           | 1               | 6           | 2706          | 
| 2018           | 1               | 12          | 36296         | 
| 2018           | 1               | 15          | 13085         | 
| 2018           | 2               | 1           | 21231         | 
| 2018           | 2               | 5           | 10242         | 
| ...            | ...             | ...         | ...           | 

55 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 18 s 374 ms 
(execution: 18 s 368 ms, fetching: 6 ms)
```

**EXPLAIN:**

```
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys                                                                                        | key                  | key_len | ref             | rows | filtered | extra                                        | 
|----|-------------|-------|------------|-------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------|---------|-----------------|------|----------|----------------------------------------------| 
| 1  | SIMPLE      | p     | null       | range | PRIMARY                                                                                              | PRIMARY              | 4       |                 | 57   | 100      | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort | 
| 1  | SIMPLE      | c     | null       | ref   | UNIQ_6F7146F0979B1AD62FC0CB0F5F8A7F73,IDX_6F7146F09395C3F3,IDX_6F7146F0979B1AD6,IDX_6F7146F0AA9E377A | IDX_6F7146F09395C3F3 | 5       | p.id            | 6716 | 8.33     | Using where                                  |
```

**DDL:**

```
create table if not exists commission (
    id int auto_increment
        primary key,
    date date not null,
    source enum('ACTUAL', 'EXPECTED') not null,
    customer_id int null,
    transaction_id varchar(255) not null,
    company_id int null,
    constraint UNIQ_6F7146F0979B1AD62FC0CB0F5F8A7F73 unique (company_id, transaction_id, source),
    constraint FK_6F7146F09395C3F3 foreign key (customer_id) references partner (id),
    constraint FK_6F7146F0979B1AD6 foreign key (company_id) references companies (id)
) collate=utf8_unicode_ci;
create index IDX_6F7146F09395C3F3 on commission (customer_id);
create index IDX_6F7146F0979B1AD6 on commission (company_id);
create index IDX_6F7146F0AA9E377A on commission (date);
```

I noted that by removing the partner `IN` condition MySQL takes only 3s. I tried to replace it doing something crazy like this:

```
AND (',3062,3063,3064,3065,3066,3067,3068,3069,3070,3071,3072,3073,3074,3075,3076,3077,3078,3079,3081,3082,3083,3084,3085,3086,3087,3088,3089,3090,3091,3092,3093,3094,3095,3096,3097,3098,3099,3448,3449,3450,3451,3452,3453,3454,3455,3456,3457,3458,3459,3460,3461,3471,3490,3491,6307,6368,6421,'
     LIKE CONCAT('%,', p.id, ',%'))
```

and the result was about 5s... great! but it's a hack.

**WHY** this query is taking a very long execution time when I uses `IN` statement? workaround, tips, links, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Where does the `p.id IN (....)` list come from?

Comment: As far as I understand, MySQL can only use one of those indexes on commission in it's WHERE; that part would better be server by a composite index on `(date, company_id, source)`.

Comment: Note if your data range is 2018, the `GROUP BY YEAR(c.date)` is constant. Its not the largest contributor to query time by far.

Comment: The `LIKE` hack won't work well because it cannot use `PRIMARY KEY(id)` on `p`.  You do have that??

Comment: @danblack - As far as the Optimizer knows `YEAR(c.date)` is _not_ a constant, since there are many values of `date`.

Comment: In some situations, the Optimizer will use an `INDEX` for `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY`.  But only if there are no expressions (eg, `YEAR()`) and all the columns come from the same table.

Comment: I was getting at there was no point adding `YEAR(c.date)` to the `GROUP BY` as the range was within 2018.  Small bit of calculation saved. Probably not much overall all depending on the result size.

Comment: @danblack - The time taken for a function call is _usually_ so insignificant (compared to fetching rows) as to be ignorable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL can use one index at a time. For this query you need a compound index covering the aspects of the search. Constant aspects of the WHERE clause should be used before range aspects like:

```
ALTER TABLE commission
DROP INDEX IDX_6F7146F0979B1AD6,
ADD INDEX IDX_6F7146F0979B1AD6 (company_id, source, date)
```

Comment: [How MySQL Uses indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: Adding a composite index on `(customer_id, company_id, date, source)` solves the performance issue (takes now less than 1s). Thanks for your answer and links.

Comment: @yceruto - Your 4-column index works well if the Optimizer starts with `p`, but you need to move `date` to the end.  Dan's 3-column index works well if it starts with `c`.  Add both.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the Optimizer sees in your query.

Checking whether to use an index for the `GROUP BY`:

- Functions (`YEAR()`) in the `GROUP BY`, so no.
- Multiple tables (`c` and `p`) mentioned, so no.

For a `JOIN`, Optimizer will (almost always) start with one, then reach into the other.  So, let's look at the two options:

If *starting* with `p`:

Assuming you have `PRIMARY KEY(id)`, there is not much to think about.  It will simply use that index.

For each row selected from `p`, it will then look into `c`, and any variation of this `INDEX` would be optimal.

```
c: INDEX(company_id, source, customer_id,  -- in any order (all are tested "=")
         date)       -- last, since it is tested as a range
```

If *starting* with `c`:

```
c: INDEX(company_id, source,  -- in any order (all are tested "=")
         date)       -- last, since it is tested as a range
-- slightly better:
c: INDEX(company_id, source,  -- in any order (all are tested "=")
         date,       -- last, since it is tested as a range
         customer_id)  -- really last -- added only to make it "covering".
```

The Optimizer will look at "statistics" to crudely decide which table to start with.  So, add all the indexes I suggested.

A "covering" index is one that contains *all* the columns needed *anywhere* in the query.  It is *sometimes* wise to extend a 'good' index with more columns to make it "covering".

But there is a monkey wrench in here.  `c.customer_id = p.id` means that `customer_id IN (...)` effectively exists.  But now there are two "range-like" constraints -- one is an `IN`, the other is a 'range'.  In some newer versions, the Optimizer will happily jump around due to the `IN` and *still* be able to do "range" scans.  So, I recommend this ordering:

1. Test(s) of `column = constant`
2. Test(s) with `IN`
3. *One* 'range' test (`BETWEEN`, `>=`, `LIKE` with trailing wildcard, etc)
4. Perhaps add more columns to make it "covering" -- but don't do this step if you end up with more than, say, 5 columns in the index.

Hence, for `c`, the following is optimal for the `WHERE`, and happens to be "covering".

```
INDEX(company_id, source,  -- first, but in any order (all "=")
      customer_id,  -- "IN"
      date)       -- last, since it is tested as a range

p: (same as above)
```

Since there was an `IN` or "range", there is no use seeing if the index can also handle the `GROUP BY`.

A note on `COUNT(x)` -- it checks that `x` is `NOT NULL`.  It is *usually* just as correct to say `COUNT(*)`, which counts the number of rows without any extra checking.

This is a non-starter since it hides the indexed column (`id`) in a function:

```
AND (',3062,3063,3064,3065,3066,...6368,6421,'
     LIKE CONCAT('%,', p.id, ',%'))
```

Comment: Yes, I tried  with `(company_id, date, customer_id, source)` is slightly better. Thanks!

Comment: The order of the columns in the index is vital to performance.  Your attempt has `date` too early.

Comment: Sorry (typo) I meant `(company_id, source, customer_id, date)` obviously :)

Comment: After the composite index > EXPLAIN > rows: 4548, filtered: 50 (for `c` table)

Comment: `55 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 548 ms (execution: 543 ms, fetching: 5 ms)`

Comment: using the original query, i.e. without the hack.

Comment: 0.548s << 18 seconds.  Can you recap on where things stand?

Answer (score 0):

With your LIKE-hack you are tricking optimizer so it uses different plan (most probably using IDX_6F7146F0AA9E377A index on the first place).
You should be able to see this in explain.

I think the real issue in your case is the second line of explain: server executing multiple functions (MONTH, YEAR) for 6716 rows and then trying to group all these rows. During this time all these 6716 rows should be stored (in memory or on disk that is based on your server configuration).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM commission WHERE (date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31') AND company_id = 90 AND source = 'ACTUAL';
```

=> How many rows are we talking about?

If the number in above query is much lower then 6716 I'd try to add covering index on columns customer_id, company_id, source and date. Not sure about the best order as it depends on data you have (check cardinality for these columns). I'd started with index (date, company_id, source, customer_id). Also, I'd add unique index (id, district_id, owner_id) on partner.

It is also possible to add additional generated stored columns _year and _month (if your server is a bit old you can add normal columns and fill them in with trigger) to rid off the multiple function executions.